# Error al intentar leer JSON, JsonConstructorAttribute is not supported - C#

Tags: c#, json

Estoy intentando abrir un archivo JSON que contiene un Bitmap, pero al momento de abrirlo me dice que

> Deserialization of types without a parameterless constructor, a singular parameterized constructor, or a parameterized constructor annotated with 'JsonConstructorAttribute' is not supported. Type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap'. Path

Mi estructura es así

```cs
class DPersonal
{
     public Bitmap Perfil { get; set; }
     public String Nombre { get; set; }
     public String Apellido { get; set; }
     public DateTime FNac { get; set; }
     public String Introduccion { get; set; }
     public String Telefono { get; set; }
     public String Correo { get; set; }
     public String Direccion { get; set; }
     public String Pagina { get; set; }
}
```

Declaracion

```cs
DPersonal P = new DPersonal();
```

La imagen la guardo con

```cs
P.Perfil = (Bitmap)Imagen.Image;
```

Lo guardo con

```cs
File.WriteAllText("Form.json", JsonSerializer.Serialize(P, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true }));
```

Y lo intento abrir con

```cs
Dpersonal P = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<DPersonal>(File.ReadAllText("Form.json"), new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });
```

Uso el paquete de Microsoft System.Text.Json;
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Estas utilizand.Net Core?

Comment: Estoy utilizando Net Framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

el error te lo dice explícitamente `Bitmap`no tiene un constructor sin parámetros, para eso te aconsejo que cambies tu modelo y la imagen la guardes como un `string`, y que conviertas ese `bitmap` a un string base 64

```
        var imageConverter = new ImageConverter();
        var bitmapDataString = Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])imageConverter.ConvertTo((Bitmap)Imagen.Image, typeof(byte[])));
```

después para setearlo en tu modelo harías

```
P.PerfilDataString = bitmapDataString;
```

después cuando vaya a mostrar su imagen debe recordar convertir a `Bitmap` el string en base 64 otra vez

```
 byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(bitmapDataString);
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(data))
        {
            P.Perfil = new Bitmap(ms);
        }
```

una última cosa sería bueno que separe los modelos para guardar los datos de los de presentar datos, pero si quiere dejar un solo modelo solo tiene que agrgar una propiedad para guardar el bitmap como string ejemplo (`PerfilDataString` ) y poner esta *annotation* en la propiedad `Perfil`

```
[JsonIgnore]     
public Bitmap Perfil { get; set; }
```

Saludos